# Creating partitioned table in postgres via Spark JDBC write

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, spark-jdbc

I want to write a dataframe to a postgres table via spark jdbc connector. The table i am writing to in postgres needs to be partitioned by a certain column. This is currently how i am writing it. I am running spark 3.2.3 and postgres 11

```
val username = "myuser"
val password = "password"
val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"

val connectionProperties = new Properties()
connectionProperties.put("user", username)
connectionProperties.put("password",password)
connectionProperties.put("partitionColumn","login_date")
connectionProperties.put("numPartitions","1")
connectionProperties.put("upperBound","2022 02-10 00:00:00")
connectionProperties.put("lowerBound","2022-02-09 00:00:00")

df.write.mode("append").jdbc(url,"pgloader",connectionProperties)
```

Initially there is no table and i run this code. It creates a table but there are no partitions coming in it. This is how the table looks when i describe it.

[image]

The column `login_date` has not been range partitioned in postgres table even though i specified it in the connection properties.

How can i create a postgres table with partitions via spark jdbc?

Comment: Have you tried repartitioning the dataframe before writing? In hive that's how I normally do it.

Comment: @cruzlorite No i didnt repartition it. Do you mean i should repartitionByKey? That would just increase the number of concurretn writes to postgres right? Would it partition the postgres table itself?

Comment: Sorry. My last comment wasn't clear. I mean using [partitionBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.partitionBy.html) while writing. That's how I normally do it. I supposed it'd be the same way writing to postgres.

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'jdbc' does not support partitioning. It returns this error. I'm guessing spark jdbc adapter does not support partitioning?

Comment: In the docs [Data Source Options](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#data-source-option) they say "Spark supports the following case-insensitive options for JDBC. The Data source options of JDBC can be set via the .option/.options methods of the DataFrameWriter". Something like `.option("partitionColumn", "mycol").option("upperBound", "...").option("lowerBound", "...")`. So probably you can not set them using the `connectionProperties`. Let me know if that solves the issue :)

Comment: Nope. That didnt create a partitioned table either. I think the only way to do it is by explicity creating a partitioned table and creating individual partitions as per the values of the incoming dataframe records. There is no automatic creation support in spark jdbc